# Can't change the password of a user with User.update() in sailsjs, fetch returns [Deferred]

Tags: node.js, database, sql-update, sails.js

I'm using postgresql(Elephant SQL) and I hadnt had issues creating and finding users inside this database. And this is my method. It's pretty straight forward and most of it shouldn't even matter to the question. What I'm lacking is the ability to change a users password, or anything really. It finds the correct user and pretty much anything up to the point where it needs to change an entry works as expected.

```
updatePassword: async function(req,res){
    if(req.body.password){
      console.log("PUT BODY" + req.body.password);
    var newPass = req.body.password;
    var userId = req.session.userId;
    var foundUser = await User.findOne({id:userId},function(err,user){
      if(err){
        return res.status(500).json({err:'database error'});
      }
      if(user){
        var hashedPass = bcrypt.hashSync(newPass, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
        console.log("Found user");
        console.log(userId);
        console.log(hashedPass);




        var updateUser = User.update(user).set({password:hashedPass}).fetch();




        console.log(updateUser);
        if(updateUser){
          return res.status(200).json({status:'success'});
        }
        else{
          return res.status(500).json({err:'database error'});

        }
      }
      if(!user){
        return res.status(500).json({err:'database error'});
      }
    });
  }
  else{
    return res.status(401).json({err:'empty body'});
  }
  },
```

I've been debugging this for quite some time and I can't figure it out at all. The user found is correct and I can get his current attributes, but I can in no way change their passwords.

Can anyone provide some insight? Maybe adding some stuff: this is a PUT request, only containing:

```
password:iaj34x
```

I can also parse the request alright. All I'm missing is the update command executing properly. The value of

> updateUser

is

> [Deferred]

And I have no idea how to get any more info on this.

Using this as an example(from the docs):

```
    await User.update({name:'Pen'})
.set({name:'Finn'});
```

I'm doing the syntax correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was missing an await next to the function. "Works" now, even though I have issues with re-logins, it changes the password in the database.

```
        var updateUser = await User.update(user).set({password:hashedPass}).fetch();
```